# Existing Obj-C function for converting strings such as "1m", "1h", "1d" to NSTimeInterval?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a string to parse that contains time periods as "1ms", "1s", "1m", "1h", "1d", "1w", "1y".

I could texturally parse it and use a case statement without too much hassle, but I was wondering if there is an existing convenience method I can just use to do this instead?

*** After 30 minutes there was no answer to my question, so I used the time to create a function from scratch as pasted below. Would still like to know however if there is a built in function that does this

```
- (NSTimeInterval) convertStringToNSTimeInterval:(NSString*) string
{
    int digitCount = 0;
    NSInteger charIdx = 0;
    for (; charIdx<string.length; charIdx++)
    {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:charIdx];
        if(c >='0' && c <='9')
        {
            ++digitCount;
        }
    }
    NSString* baseString = [string  substringToIndex: digitCount];
    double base = [baseString doubleValue];
    NSString* timeUnit = [string substringFromIndex:digitCount];

    if (NSOrderedSame == [timeUnit caseInsensitiveCompare:@"Y"])
    {
        base *= 365.242199;
    }
    else if (NSOrderedSame == [timeUnit caseInsensitiveCompare:@"D"])
    {
        base *= (24 * 60 * 60);
    }
    else if (NSOrderedSame == [timeUnit caseInsensitiveCompare:@"H"])
    {
        base *= (60 * 60);
    }
    else if (NSOrderedSame == [timeUnit caseInsensitiveCompare:@"M"])
    {
        base *= 60;
    }
    else if (NSOrderedSame == [timeUnit caseInsensitiveCompare:@"S"])
    {
        // Already in seconds
    }
    else if (NSOrderedSame == [timeUnit caseInsensitiveCompare:@"W"])
    {
        base *= (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }
    else if (NSOrderedSame == [timeUnit caseInsensitiveCompare:@"MS"])
    {
        base /= 1000;
    }

    NSTimeInterval result = base;
    [Model log: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"convertStringToNSTimeInterval. Converting from: %@", string]];
    [Model log: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"convertStringToNSTimeInterval. result: %f seconds", result]];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you can add your solution as an answer, I'd do that.